Postgres `server closed the connection unexpectedly` On Port That's Listened To
Description

I have a PostgreSQL DB in a VPC (10.2.0.0/24) that I'm attempt to remotely connect to from a second VPC (10.21.0.0/16).

I have an AWS VPC Peering connection setup between both VPCs and I'm able to open connections between VPCs for different uses.
When I attempt to connect via the second VPN I get
psql --host=10.2.1.227 --username={username} {db_name}
psql: error: connection to server at "10.2.1.227", port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.

but when I attempt to connect from the original VPN I get
psql --host=10.2.1.227 --username={username} {db_name}
Password for user {username}:

Note that I'm using IPs for all of these examples to keep this simple.
nmap says that port 5432 is open on the accepting host
Starting Nmap 7.94SVN ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-11-20 00:04 UTC
Initiating Ping Scan at 00:04
Scanning 10.2.1.227 [4 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 00:04, 0.01s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 00:04
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 00:04, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 00:04
Scanning ip-10-2-1-227.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.2.1.227) [1 port]
Discovered open port 5432/tcp on 10.2.1.227
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 00:04, 0.01s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for ip-10-2-1-227.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.2.1.227)
Host is up (0.00034s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
5432/tcp open  postgresql

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 5 (196B) | Rcvd: 2 (84B)

On the host machine I can see that the ports are being listened to
netstat -nlp | grep 5432
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3258135978 -                    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432

I can see my config file locations
seasensor=# show hba_file;
              hba_file
-------------------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)
seasensor=# SHOW config_file;
               config_file
-----------------------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
(1 row)


and I have reloaded my configuration files

seasensor=# SELECT pg_reload_conf();
 pg_reload_conf
----------------
 t
(1 row)

both dynamically and through a full service restart.
I verified thatpostgresql.conf has (this is a DB that's been accepting connections for a while)
listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;

and pg_hba.conf to have
host    all             all             10.21.0.0/16           md5

Hell, I set pg_hba.conf to
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0           md5

for a hot second just to make sure this wasn't the issue.
There's a security group on the EC2 instance I'm attempt to connect to that allows for connections from 10.21.0.0/16 on port 5432
And when I run TCP dump I can see that the IPs and ports are what I expect
00:37:30.457060 ens5  Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7229, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.21.6.191.36260 > 10.2.1.227.5432: Flags [P.], cksum 0x1ce7 (incorrect -> 0x487f), seq 1:9, ack 1, win 981, options [nop,nop,TS val 2016222916 ecr 3695341051], length 8
E..<.=@.@...
...
......8..U................
x-...Bm......../


I've even tried configuring tcp-keep alive on the host machine.
Running netstat during the attempted connection I can see that a connection is established
netstat -tupn | grep -E ":(5432) .*"
tcp        0      1 10.2.1.227:5432         10.21.6.191:37882       ESTABLISHED 14630/postgres
tcp        0      0 10.2.1.227:5432         10.2.2.104:55640        ESTABLISHED 12997/postgres: 10/

One thing that caught my eye was the different program identified with netstat at the end there between connections from either VPC.
So I'm confused as to what's going on in this case and even how to find out more information about what's specifically going wrong.
Edit
I wanted to double check to make sure everything was loaded.
select * from pg_file_settings where name = "listen_address";
 /etc/postgresql/10/main/conf.d/00_server.conf     |          1 |    24 | listen_addresses                | *                                       | t       |

select * from pg_hba_file_rules
         100 | host  | {all}         | {all}      | 10.21.0.0   | 255.255.0.0                             | md5         |         |  |
         106 | host  | {all}         | {all}      | 10.2.0.0    | 255.255.252.0                           | md5         |         |

Second Edit
I can see that connections are being seen by the DB but I'm not able to get further information about why the psql connection isn't being established from the logs. At least not with log_connections and log_disconnections turned on
$ grep -Irsn "10.21.6.191" /data/pg_log/postgresql-2024-11-26_*
/data/pg_log/postgresql-2024-11-26_214912.log:97:2024-11-26 21:49:35.318 UTC [5693] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  connection received: host=10.21.6.191 port=57842


Perhaps reviewing the PostgreSQL server log entries at around the failed connection time provide some useful information; did you have a chance to look at them?

Apologies for the late follow-up. I haven't had power for basically a week at this point. Looking at the logs I see the first connection log entry that says a TCP connection is established [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  connection received: host=10.21.6.191 port=59626 but not the second log entry that says that a psql server connection is established.
